# Moving through allocated bytes

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, byte

I have following declaration data:

```
temp db 50 DUP(0)
```

How do I access each byte?
Let's say I do `mov temp, 48` and then want to move 49 into the next byte of the allocated ones. I tried to

```
inc temp
mov temp, 49
```

but it just increased temp value to 49

Comment: possible duplicate of [accessing array's element in assembly language (windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864011/accessing-arrays-element-in-assembly-language-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.

```
mov [temp + 1], 49
```

or, if you want to dynamically select the slot in temp to store a value in

```
mov [temp + ebx], 49
```

where ebx holds the index value (could be any register)